# I couldn't place Tables between two lines in Elsarticle template

Tags: tables

[image]

Hey guys. I spent the whole day try to figure out how to place a table in two lines as shown in the figure using Elsarticle template. I'm  using Overleaf.
I use \hrulefill, but the bottom line goes far and sometine jumps to the next page.
There is some of my attempts.

```
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{belowskip=2pt, position=above, labelsep=space, 
         justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=off}
\begin{table}[!hbt]
    \centering
    \hrulefill
    \caption{statistics of the dataset time series} 
    \label{dataset-statistics}
    \begin{tabular}{c |c |c |c |c } 
     \hline 
          & USDX & TENI & SENT & Brent Price \\
         \hline
        count & 2386.000000 & 2386.000000 & 2386.000000 & 2386.000000 \\
        mean & 91.235038 & 5499.590413 & -7266.280387 & 72.182456 \\
        std & 7.260205 & 1144.304023 & 3245.959430 & 26.626707 \\
        min & 78.270000 & 3459.530000 & -14033.466070 & 19.330000 \\
        25\% & 82.602500 & 4657.027500 & -9692.075176 & 50.862500 \\
        50\% & 94.010000 & 5216.730000 & -7042.827047 & 63.765000 \\
        75\% & 97.100000 & 6139.666875 & -4602.503936 & 103.885000 \\
        max & 103.250000 & 9119.820000 & 18.786006 & 126.22000 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\hrulefill
```

Can you help please?

Comment: the hrulefill at the end obviously need to be before the `\end{table}` if it is connected to the table, not to the main document flow. why `[!hbt]` this omits `p` so makes it more likely that tables float to the end of the document (and `!` should only be used in special cases, it doesn't make sense to use it routinely as it means "ignore the default settings")

Comment: thank you for your comments @DavidCarlisle

Comment: BTW, you should look into the `booktabs` package.  It will help with the different thicknesses of horizontal lines.  But it will not like your vertical lines, which should be deleted anyway.

Comment: Why would you change the setup for table captions in `elsarticle`, which is meant for submissions to Elsevier journals?

Comment: @egreg I'm beginner. I downloaded used the elsarticle-template-num.tex example. When I create a table, it doesn't take the Elsiver format directly  respecting to tables. 
I don't know if some files missing or I'm doing something wrong. any insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

okay, I solved it this way.

```
\begin{table}[!hbt]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.45pc}
\hrule
\centering

    \begin{tabular}{@{}l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
    \hline
       .....
\end{tabular} 
\vspace{3mm}
\hrule
\centering
\end{table}
```